# VBA Filter Based on Checked Boxes

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, userform

I was wondering if anyone could help me out. I have created a user form that changes the filters on an excel sheet. I have column that contains a priority level from 1-3. When the form is launched i have a option to print the report to PDF, but i want to allow the user to apply/filter out result based on the priority, before they print to PDF. I have three check boxes that i want to use in a filter code (See image below). This where i get stuck, i am not sure how to input code into the Criteria portion so when the user would check the box priority 1, it would filter out that section before it prints. I was going to assign the numerical value that is associated with priority if the value is true. Then use that number as the value "criteria" when the filter is applied. Is there a better way to do this?

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$W$7:$AG$4501").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria:= "What Do i Put Here?"
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there a column filled with priority? If so, filter on that value. Did you look up any answers about how to use `Range.Autofilter`? There are plenty of solutions on that

Comment: Yes the column is filled with the priority level (updated picture above). I was able to find information on the Range.Autofilter, but i am struggling to find info on how to link the value of the checkbox to the required criteria for the autofilter. If the user checks the priority level 1 box and clicks ok i want the autofilter to associate a true value as a 1 in the range autofilter criteria and any combination of check priority.

Comment: This isn't relevant but does this really need to rely on `ActiveSheet`?

Comment: That is a good point, no it does not need to be active sheet. I can define the sheet is applies to.

Answer (score 0):

You will just need to check the names of the check-boxes and line them up to the correct criteria. Notice that your criteria is just the value you want to filter, here `1, 2, or 3`.

For your test statement, you could also just say `If CheckBox1 Then` which will return either `If True Then` where `True` corresponds to a checked box.

I wrote it out explicitly in the below code so it is clear. I'm guessing this will probably need to be called when a submit button of some sort is clicked.

---

```
If CheckBox1 = True Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("$W$7:$AG$4501").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria:= 1
ElseIf CheckBox2 = True Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("$W$7:$AG$4501").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria:= 2
ElseIf CheckBox3 = True Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("$W$7:$AG$4501").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria:= 3
End If
```

Comment: Yeah i have a button that will call this code. This code above only allows for one priority to be applied. If they user selects 1 and 3 then only priority 1 will be applied. I had a similar code above with all the combination and was trying to clean it up.